# A program or code to grab RSS feed subscription links and take screenshots

Tags: hyperlink, rss, screenshot, feed

I'm new here and I have one crazy first question.

Is there a program or code that I can run daily that will automatically grab rss feed subscription links and compile them in a list. Either in an HTML file or text file? We're talking 400+ RSS subscriptions from an online service (feedly) or something like feed demon and would only be newly updated items. Once grabbed I'd need them marked all as read. Rince and repeat every day.

Also I'd need it to have something follow those subscription links and take website screenshots.

Is there any combination of things (or just something) that can do those things? The first one is the most important though.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to do everything yourself, you can write a script to get the XML feed, extract the URL link, an call PhantomJS to take a screenshot. You can also check screenshot services that offer custom projects like Browshot (https://browshot.com) and others.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I'm thinking of going with a screenshot service for sure. I'd still need the new/unread RSS feed links though. Any idea on how to write such a script? Is it easy and what would I need?

Comment: The RSS feed is in XML. You can extract the <url> tag and save it in a database (sqlite, for example) to check what you have already requested. Browsho tcan take care of this for you.